# Spring Boot Upload multiple files with attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, postman, multipartform-data

I have student and documents. I have an api to add students with documents.

Example parameters:

```yaml
name: Student Name
age: 10
gender: m
documents:
  - name: "school certificate"
    code: "sc"
    file: <multipart file>
  - name: "transfer certificate"  
    code: "tc"
    file: <multipart file>
  - name: "avatar"
    code: "avatar"
    file: <multipart file>
```

I have created two classes:

```kotlin
class Student {
  var name: String = ""
  var age: Int = 0
  var gender: String = "m"
  var files: List<Document>? = null
}

class Document {
  var name: String? = null
  var code: String? = null
  var file: MultipartFile? = null
}
```

I have added a controller.

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ["/test"], produces = ["application/json"])
class StudentController {

  @PostMapping("/student")
  fun student(
    @ModelAttribute student: Student
  ):  String? {
    return student.name
  }
}
```

I have tried calling the API in postman.

[image: Screenshot of postman API calling]

I got the response as below.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1589357162828,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Invalid property 'files[0][code]' of bean class [com.example.Student]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'files[0][code]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [com.example.Document@1801d05f]",
    "path": "/test/student"
}
```

I am not sure what went wrong here. Please help me on this.

Comment: try changing `files` type to `MutableList`

Comment: @sidgate Thanks for your response. I have tried that, but same result.

Comment: @Sayuj - you got any solution to above problem?